# How do I force a command to be run on local login?

Tags: security, login, command

I was wondering how do I force a command on login of a linux system? (debian 7). This is for a 2FA authentication command.

- I am asking for a local login.. not ssh.

Comment: That will largely depend on your system/distro, and how well you can handle PAM (if your distro uses pam). More detail, please.

Comment: I am using debian 7. I just want to force a command to make DuoSecurity 2FA run.

In the DuoSecurity docs I can only find how to force a command via SSH. Not via local login.

Comment: I don't have a debian box here to play with, but I'll hazard a guess and say their https://www.duosecurity.com/docs/duounix#ubuntu will work. As you can see this talks about auth in general, not just ssh, so you SHOULD be able to make it work in the way you desire.

Comment: So you want to run a command **as part of** authentication, right? Not after a successful authentication? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: After a successful login is when I want the command to run.